# How can I create multiple non-contiguous cartograms with the same underlying scale using cartogram_ncont() in R?

Tags: r, maps, spatial, scaling, cartogram

### My Goal

I would like to visualise the spatial variation in election results on a map. This would answer the question: how did each electoral district vote? In particular, I would like to use **[non-contiguous cartograms](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.0033-0124.1976.00371.x)** and scale each district's area according to the **count of votes cast** for each party.

Hence, I produce **one map per party**, where the **size of the district** reflects the **number of votes cast** for that party in that district. For better visual recognition, the districts are coloured in the party's colour. To achieve all this, I use the function [`cartogram_ncont()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cartogram/versions/0.2.2/topics/cartogram_ncont) of the package [`cartogram`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cartogram/versions/0.2.2) in [`R`](https://www.r-project.org/).

### My Problem

The resulting **scale is *not consistent* across maps**. In other words, the maps are *well-suited* to campare where *a single party* did better or worse, but they are *ill-suited* to compare *which party* did better or worse. Put differently still, there currently is one "**anchor district**" on each map which isn't shrunk. However, I would like there to be only one "**anchor district**" across all maps, namely the district with the *highest ballot* count in the *entire data set*. Hence, the range of *all* vote counts for *all* parties should set the scale, not the range of vote counts for *each individual* party.

### My Examples

See as an example the results of the two parties with *the most* and *the least* votes overall in the [Upper Austrian elections in 2015](https://www.wahldatenbank.at/):

[OEVP - most votes overall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxqdb.jpg)

[CPOE - least votes overall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PffVI.jpg)

### My Solution?

I realise that [`cartogram_ncont()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cartogram/versions/0.2.2/topics/cartogram_ncont) takes an optional argument `k` which determines how many districts on the map are shrunk and how many are inflated. Yet, I don't understand *whether or how* I can use this argument to compute all my non-contiguous cartograms to the same underlying scale.

***Any hints and ideas would be very welcome for I find myself at an impasse!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an interesting question. A sample code would have been helpful for my answer.

Playing around with the k values could be tricky. So I would like to suggest a simpler solution: just combine all variables into one value vector and use that for the cartogram.

I have modified the example from the cartogram_ncont() man page to give you a small demonstration. I did used the `sp`-package, but you can easily adopt the code for `sf`.

```
library(maptools)
library(cartogram)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

data(wrld_simpl)

# Remove uninhabited regions
afr <- spTransform(wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl$REGION==2 & wrld_simpl$POP2005 > 0,],
                   CRS("+init=epsg:3395"))

# and keep only countries with larger area
afr <- afr[afr$AREA > 2568, ]

# Create fake data
set.seed(1234)
afr$V1 <- runif(nrow(afr), 0, 0.08) * 100
afr$V2 <- runif(nrow(afr), 0.3, 0.7) * 100
afr$V3 <- 100 - afr$V2 - afr$V1

# Keep the value for Egypt and Algeria constant
# this allows us to inspect the resulting map
afr$V1[afr$FIPS=="EG"] <- 40
afr$V2[afr$FIPS=="EG"] <- 40
afr$V3[afr$FIPS=="EG"] <- 40

afr$V1[afr$FIPS=="AG"] <- 13
afr$V2[afr$FIPS=="AG"] <- 13
afr$V3[afr$FIPS=="AG"] <- 13

# color vector for plotting
afr$col <- "gray"
afr$col[afr$FIPS=="EG"] <- "red"
afr$col[afr$FIPS=="AG"] <- "blue"
```

Now we need to create a SpatialDataFrame in long format. So we use `rbind` to    bind polygons and variable values together. The cartogram is based on this new dataset.

```
# There is probably a more efficient way to do this...

# create temporary data
tmp <- afr
tmp$W <- tmp$V1      # assign V1 to new weight variable
tmp$variable <- "V1" # add information about variable

# do the same for all other variables and rbind the spatial data
for(v in c("V2", "V3")) {
  tt <- afr
  tt$W <- tt[[v]]
  tt$variable <- v
  tmp <- rbind(tmp, tt)
}

# cartogram calculation
afr_nc <- cartogram_ncont(tmp, "W", k = 8)
```

Now we can plot the distorted map.

```
# plot side-by-side
par(mfrow = c(1,3))
for(v in c("V1", "V2", "V3")) {
  plot(afr)
  plot(afr_nc[afr_nc$variable==v, ], add=T, col = afr_nc$col)
}
```

[image: cartogram for 3 different variables]

```
# overplot new polygons
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
plot(afr)
for(v in c("V1", "V2", "V3")) {
  plot(afr_nc[afr_nc$variable==v, ], add=T, col = "#00000022")
}
```

[image: overlayed new boundaries]

Comment: Many thanks - your approach helped me solve my specific example! Using one long variable and indexing it is a neat solution - I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem Solved - Thanks to sjewo!

Using **sjewos** solution I was able to produce the **cartograms for Upper Austria**. Here they are, FYI.

If you want to run the **source code**, make sure to adapt the **working directory** within the script to your desired path. The map of election districts should download automatically.

The **election results** are **chosen randomly** because they are hard to download and handle programmatically.

I produce both **uniformly coloured** cartograms as well as cartograms with a **colour scale**.

### The resulting maps

I hold the election results of three districts (**Wels**, **Linz** and **Mondsee**) constant. Notice how they stick out - especially on maps with a colour scale. Here are some examples:

[OEVP_Colour_Constant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ3PY.png)

[OEVP_Colour_Scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9gNv.png)

[FPOE_Colour_Constant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRNc0.png)

[FPOE_Colour_Scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi6yW.png)

[SPOE_Colour_Constant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU1Mv.png)

[SPOE_Colour_Scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VG1d.png)

[NEOS_Colour_Constant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVNfR.png)

[NEOS_Colour_Scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4tj5.png)

### The source code

There are numerous **inline comments** - I hope they are sufficient explanation of what happens!

```
# Cartograms - how to scale multiple maps to the same benchmark?
# 
# Non-contiguous cartograms
#
# Dendron's question:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68685129
#
# Implementing sjewo's answer:
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/68716489

# load packages
library("sf")
library("dplyr")
library("rgdal")
library("maptools")
library("cartogram")
library("foreach")
library("doParallel")
library("graphics")
library("s2dv")
library("rgeos")

# Settings
ext    <- 'png'    # file type
a      <- 1        # alpha
gren   <- "grey"   # colour for border line
wd     <- '/path/to/your/working/directory'
setwd(wd)
file1  <- paste(wd,'GEMEINDEGRENZEN_GEN', 'GEMEINDEGRENZEN_GEN.shp', sep = '/')
par_1  <- 0.7                    # scaling factor for fonts
par_2  <- c(0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1)     # margins for multi-panel-plotting
par_3  <- c(0.05,0.85,0.05,0.95) # borders for panels
kk     <- 1                      # expansion factor

# Download & unzip .shp file
link  <- "https://e-gov.ooe.gv.at/at.gv.ooe.dorisdaten/DORIS_Basisdaten/GEMEINDEGRENZEN_GEN.zip"
file3 <- paste(wd,'GEMEINDEGRENZEN_GEN.zip',sep='/')
download.file(link,file3)
unzip(file3, exdir = 'GEMEINDEGRENZEN_GEN')

# Import Upper Austria's election districts
map   <- read_sf(dsn = file1)

# Choose some parties to participate in the election
part  <- c("oevp",  "fpoe",  "spoe", "gruene", "neos")

# Invent election results
set.seed(20210823)
map[['oevp']] <- runif(nrow(map),0,1)

foreach(g=2:length(part))%do%{
        
        # Make each party's results less than the previous'
        map[[part[g]]] <- map[[part[g-1]]]/2
        
        # Keep some values constant for comparison
        map[[part[g]]][map$GEM_NAME=="Wels"] = 1
        map[[part[g]]][map$GEM_NAME=="Mondsee"] = 0.5
        map[[part[g]]][map$GEM_NAME=="Linz"] = 0
}

# Summarise all election results into one variable
tmp       <- map
tmp$votes <- tmp[[part[1]]]
names(tmp$votes) <- 'votes'
tmp$part  <- part[1]

for(v in part[2:length(part)]) {
        tt       <- map
        tt$votes <- tt[[v]]
        tt$part  <- v
        tmp      <- rbind(tmp, tt)
}

# Hand-pick colours and colour scales which match the parties' branding
farb  <- c("#64c4d2","#044ee1","#ff0000","#00d600","#ff4ccf","#8C0307","#000000")

tuerk <-     c("#FFFFFF", "#F7FCFD", "#F0F9FB", "#E8F6F8", "#E0F3F6", "#D8F0F4",
               "#D1EDF2", "#C9EAEF", "#C1E7ED", "#B9E4EB", "#B2E2E9", "#AADFE6",
               "#A2DCE4", "#9AD9E2", "#93D6E0", "#8BD3DD", "#83D0DB", "#7BCDD9",
               "#74CAD7", "#6CC7D4", "#64C4D2")
blau  <-     c("#FFFFFF", "#F2F6FE", "#E6EDFC", "#D9E4FB", "#CDDCF9", "#C0D3F8",
               "#B4CAF6", "#A7C1F5", "#9BB8F3", "#8EAFF2", "#82A7F0", "#759EEF",
               "#6895ED", "#5C8CEC", "#4F83EA", "#437AE9", "#3671E7", "#2A69E6",
               "#1D60E4", "#1157E3", "#044EE1")
rot   <-     c("#FFFFFF", "#FFF2F2", "#FFE6E6", "#FFD9D9", "#FFCCCC", "#FFBFBF",
               "#FFB3B3", "#FFA6A6", "#FF9999", "#FF8C8C", "#FF8080", "#FF7373",
               "#FF6666", "#FF5959", "#FF4D4D", "#FF4040", "#FF3333", "#FF2626",
               "#FF1A1A", "#FF0D0D", "#FF0000")
gruen <-     c("#FFFFFF", "#F2FDF2", "#E6FBE6", "#D9F9D9", "#CCF7CC", "#BFF5BF",
               "#B3F3B3", "#A6F1A6", "#99EF99", "#8CED8C", "#80EB80", "#73E873",
               "#66E666", "#59E459", "#4DE24D", "#40E040", "#33DE33", "#26DC26",
               "#1ADA1A", "#0DD80D", "#00D600")
pink  <-     c("#FFFFFF", "#FFF6FD", "#FFEDFA", "#FFE4F8", "#FFDBF5", "#FFD2F3",
               "#FFC9F1", "#FFC0EE", "#FFB7EC", "#FFAEE9", "#FFA6E7", "#FF9DE5",
               "#FF94E2", "#FF8BE0", "#FF82DD", "#FF79DB", "#FF70D9", "#FF67D6",
               "#FF5ED4", "#FF55D1", "#FF4CCF")
purp  <-     c("#FFFFFF", "#F9F2F3", "#F4E6E6", "#EED9DA", "#E8CDCD", "#E2C0C1",
               "#DDB3B5", "#D7A7A8", "#D19A9C", "#CB8E8F", "#C68183", "#C07477",
               "#BA686A", "#B45B5E", "#AF4F51", "#A94245", "#A33539", "#9D292C",
               "#981C20", "#921013", "#8C0307")
schw  <-     c("#FFFFFF", "#F2F2F2", "#E6E6E6", "#D9D9D9", "#CCCCCC", "#BFBFBF",
               "#B3B3B3", "#A6A6A6", "#999999", "#8C8C8C", "#808080", "#737373",
               "#666666", "#595959", "#4D4D4D", "#404040", "#333333", "#262626",
               "#1A1A1A", "#0D0D0D", "#000000")

# Combine colour maps
pally <- cbind(tuerk, blau, rot, gruen, pink, purp, schw)

# Choose breaks for colour scale
brks  <- seq(0, 1, length.out = length(rot)+1)

# Choose sensible ticks for colour bar
ll    <- seq(min(brks),max(brks), length.out = 3)

# Create base map
base     <- st_geometry(map)

# Calculate Cartogram
ooe_scal <- cartogram_ncont(tmp, 'votes', k=kk, inplace = TRUE)

# Setup parallel cluster
cores=detectCores()

# Do not overload your computer
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]-1)
registerDoParallel(cl)

# Loop over parties
foreach(i=1:length(part),
        .packages = c("cartogram","sf","foreach","s2dv","graphics","rgdal","rgeos"))%dopar%{
                
                # ----- WITH COLOUR SCALE ----- #
                
                # Pick title/filename
                tt <- paste(part[i], 'scale', sep = '_')
                
                # start recording plot
                png(file=paste(tt, ext, sep = '.'))
                
                # Reset plotting device
                layout(1)
                par(cex=par_1, mai=par_2)
                par(fig=par_3)
                
                # Background map
                plot(base, axes = FALSE, border = gren)
                
                # Generate colour palette
                pp <- colorRampPalette(pally[,i], space = "rgb", interpolate = "linear")
                
                # Visualise
                cc <- which(colnames(ooe_scal)==part[i], arr.ind = TRUE)
                plot(ooe_scal[cc][ooe_scal$part==part[i],], pal = pp,
                     axes = FALSE, border = gren, add = TRUE, alpha = a, breaks = brks)
                
                # Add description
                title(tt)
                
                # Visualise colour scale on bar
                par(fig=c(0.9,1,0.2,0.8), new=TRUE)
                ColorBar(brks = brks, cols = pally[,i], plot = TRUE,
                         vertical = TRUE, label_digits = 2, extra_labels = ll)
                
                # Save output
                dev.off()
                
                # ----- WITH CONSTANT COLOURS ----- #
                
                # Pick title/filename
                tt <- paste(part[i], 'const', sep = '_')
                
                # start recording plot
                png(file=paste(tt, ext, sep = '.'))
                
                # Reset plotting device
                layout(1)
                
                # Background map
                plot(base, axes = FALSE, border = gren)
                
                # Visualise
                cc <- which(colnames(ooe_scal)==part[i], arr.ind = TRUE)
                plot(ooe_scal[cc][ooe_scal$part==part[i],], col = c(farb[i]),
                     axes = FALSE, border = gren, add = TRUE, alpha = a, breaks = brks)
                
                # Add description
                title(tt)
                
                # Save output
                dev.off()
        }

# stop cluster
stopCluster(cl)

# <EOF>
```